# SQL: delete records from the table A when id is less than equal to maximum id of a group in table B

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-optimization

I have 2 tables **arh** and **ar** .I need to delete records from arh table for each accountMappingId where actionRequestId is <= maximum actionRequestId for the operation 'RESTORE' on the equivalent mappingId in ar table. The records should be deleted only in arh table without affecting ar table.

**There can be different accountMappingId (1001, 1002, 1003).**

-- create table --

```
create table arh (
  accountMappingId TEXT,
  actionRequestId integer,
  actionrequesthistoryid integer
);

CREATE TABLE ar (
  mappingId TEXT,
  actionRequestId integer,
  operation TEXT
);
```

-- insert records ---

```
INSERT INTO arh VALUES ('1001', 1, 1);
INSERT INTO arh VALUES ('1001', 1, 2);
INSERT INTO arh VALUES ('1001', 2, 1);
INSERT INTO arh VALUES ('1001', 2, 2);
INSERT INTO arh VALUES ('1001', 3, 1);
INSERT INTO arh VALUES ('1001', 3, 2);
INSERT INTO arh VALUES ('1001', 4, 1);
INSERT INTO arh VALUES ('1001', 4, 2);
INSERT INTO arh VALUES ('1001', 5, 1);
INSERT INTO arh VALUES ('1001', 5, 2);
INSERT INTO arh VALUES ('1001', 6, 1);
INSERT INTO arh VALUES ('1001', 6, 2);
INSERT INTO arh VALUES ('1001', 7, 1);
INSERT INTO arh VALUES ('1001', 7, 2);
INSERT INTO arh VALUES ('1001', 8, 1);
INSERT INTO arh VALUES ('1001', 8, 2);
INSERT INTO arh VALUES ('1002', 1, 1);
INSERT INTO arh VALUES ('1002', 1, 2);
INSERT INTO arh VALUES ('1002', 2, 1);
INSERT INTO arh VALUES ('1002', 2, 2);
INSERT INTO arh VALUES ('1002', 3, 1);
INSERT INTO arh VALUES ('1002', 3, 2);
```

```
INSERT INTO ar VALUES ('1001', 1, 'COPY');
INSERT INTO ar VALUES ('1001', 2, 'REMOVE');
INSERT INTO ar VALUES ('1001', 3, 'RESTORE');
INSERT INTO ar VALUES ('1001', 4, 'COPY');
INSERT INTO ar VALUES ('1001', 5, 'REMOVE');
INSERT INTO ar VALUES ('1001', 6, 'RESTORE'); --> max(actionrequestId) for 'RESTORE' operation in '1001'
INSERT INTO ar VALUES ('1001', 7, 'COPY');
INSERT INTO ar VALUES ('1001', 8, 'REMOVE');
INSERT INTO ar VALUES ('1002', 1, 'COPY');
INSERT INTO ar VALUES ('1002', 2, 'REMOVE');
INSERT INTO ar VALUES ('1002', 3, 'RESTORE'); --> max(actionrequestId) for 'RESTORE' operation in '1002'
```

**Solution what I have tried but can we optimize the delete query?**

```
delete from arh 
where (arh.actionRequestId, arh.accountMappingId) in (
select arh.actionRequestId, new_table.mappingId
from arh 
inner join (
  SELECT mappingId, max(actionrequestid) as actionrequestid
  FROM ar 
  where operation = 'RESTORE'
  group by mappingid
  ) 
as new_table
on arh.accountMappingId = new_table.mappingId
and arh.actionRequestId <= new_table.actionRequestId
order by arh.actionRequestId, new_table.mappingId)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a subquery to get the Mapping ID's maximum RESTORE request ID.

```
DELETE FROM arh
WHERE actionRequestId <= ( SELECT MAX(ar.actionRequestId) 
                           FROM ar
                           WHERE ar.operation = 'RESTORE' 
                           AND ar.mappingId = arh.accountMappingId );
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/Frx1Ea3_

Comment: Yes this is the solution for the task described in the request. In their original statement they compare the mapping IDs, however. So I suppose they forgot to include this in the description. If that is the case, we will have to add `AND mappingId = arh.accountMappingId` to the subquery.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Thanks for pointing out the mappingId addition. There is an update in question. The join / match should be on mappingId and then delete the  records from the group.

Comment: @Govind Yadav: I've updated SIdhartha's answer accordingly. Now you have two correct answers showing different methods on how to delete the rows.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Yes both the solution are better than the original solution. Right now, I am doing testing on a smaller table in dev environment both the query look good. I am wondering which of the 2 correct answers will be better if I am running the query on a table with 20 million records in production and why it will be better. can you guide me on that?

Comment: No, I could only guess. With very few mapping IDs ahmed's approach may be better for selecting the few maximum request IDs first and then only looking up this small table. With very many mapping IDs SIdhartha's approach may be faster for not generating a big lookup table, And then maybe the optimizer chooses the same execution plan for both, seeing that the two statements do exactly the same. Use `EXPLAIN` to see the difference.

Comment: An ar index on mappingId, operation and actionRequestId would be helpful, anyway. Best index may be `create index idx on ar (mappingId, actionRequestId) where operation = 'RESTORE' `.

Comment: Maybe the statement would even benefit from an additional arh index: `create index idx_arh on arh (accountMappingId, actionRequestId)`.

Answer (score 1):

You could find the `max(actionRequestId)` from ar table where `operation = 'RESTORE'`, then use the `USING` clause to delete the desired rows from arh table.

```
delete from arh T
using 
(
  select mappingId, max(actionRequestId) max_actionRequestId
  from ar
  where operation = 'RESTORE'
  group by mappingId
) D
where T.accountMappingId = D.mappingId and
   T.actionRequestId <= D.max_actionRequestId
```

[See demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/vXI4BhpE)